# ng2-complete search data undefined angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng2-completer

Following problem: I receive an error from chrome browser search undefined and I am using dataservice which loads local JSON data
.

Comment: Can you add-in your snippet ?

Comment: the issue was resolved after inistialising the dataService with null